# Ran update query without where clause. How to revert changes without backup file

Tags: sql-server-2008

Ran update query without where clause. How to revert changes without backup file.
in MSSQL server 2008.

Comment: `Rollback` if you haven't yet committed it.

Comment: committed it???? I have ran this query: update tableName set columnName='value'

Comment: If you have run the statement from a client which doesn't auto-commit, you can roll it back, using "rollback;".

Comment: the rollback transaction request has no corresponding begin transaction

Comment: Do you have history/audit tables where you stored historical data?

Comment: Check: http://solutioncenter.apexsql.com/recover-sql-server-data-from-accidental-updates/